# How should one deal with Boxed trait objects in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a trait `Expression` which is defined on multiple types. A typical pattern I tend to include in my types is `Box<dyn Expression>`. Here's an example:

```rust
pub struct BinaryExpr {
 l : Box<dyn Expression>, r : Box<dyn Expression>
}
```

I have another trait `ExpressionPrinter` which is defined like :

```rust
pub trait ExpressionPrinter: Expression {
 fn print(&self); 
}
```

As you can see, it takes a immutable reference to self, and is supposed to print a string representation of the any expression type implementing it.  Let's say I was implementing this for `BinaryExpr`

```rust
impl ExpressionPrinter for BinaryExpr {
    fn print(&self)  {
        let mut s = start!("BinaryExp");
        s.push_str(&self.operator.lexeme);
        s.push_str(&self.left.print());
        s.push_str(&self.right.print());
        dbg!(s);
    }
}
```

This code does not compile because :
[image]

Alright, maybe I need to deref from `Box` before calling the methods, but wait, isn't Box supposed to auto-deref? Then I looked around the docs for `Box` realizing I don't really understand Boxed trait objects. There's an `into_inner` but it doesn't work as the inner trait object is `!Sized`. There's a downcast which

> Attempt to downcast the box to a concrete type.

But it requires trait `Any` to be implemented for each expression type.

Needless to say, this abstraction is not fun anymore with so many restrictions. I don't understand how to call trait object methods.

EDIT: The question as it stands now is how do I cast from a `Box<dyn Expression>` to a concrete type bounded by `ExpressionPrinter`?

Comment: In `self.left.print()`, `self.left` is a box of `dyn Expression`. That's all you know about it. But print is a method of `ExpressionPrinter`, and not all `Expression`s are `ExpressionPrinter`s. `Box` does auto-deref, but not to a different trait.

Comment: You'd have to downcast the box to `Box<dyn ExpressionPrinter>` to make this work, and that's a bit of a code smell. Better would be to codify this behavior on `Expression`, if it's something that is common to all expressions.

Comment: Smells like too many traits. Will you ever really care to reference _only_ an `ExpressionPrinter` without the `Expression` part? Also, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You reference `left`, `right`, and `operator` but those don't even exist - and your `push_str` accepts `&()`?

Comment: One solution is to make `Display` a supertrait of `Expression` – basically the opposite of what you did.

Comment: @cdhowie that was the answer I was looking for and it was completely missing me. Maybe I was too tired, but I was trying to call `ExpressionPrinter` methods on a `dyn Expression`. Which brings me to downcasting, don't we require `Any` trait bound to downcast as I mentioned in my question? Also can you write the code on calling a `dyn Expression` as a `dyn ExpressionPrinter`?

Comment: @purple_turtle Yes, you'd need a `dyn Any` which is a bit involved to obtain, more than I can really put in an SO comment. You'd be better off inverting your two traits, I think (or combining them into one).

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is not how you implement AST in rust. This is not java or other strongly OOP language. What you should use are Algebraic types (`enum`s). These types allow to store multiple memory layouts inside one type. Here is an example:

```rust
pub enum Expr {
    Int(i64),
    String(String),
    Binary {
        op: String,
        left: Box<Expr>,
        right: Box<Expr>,
    }
    Unary {
        op: String,
        operand: Box<Expr>,
    }
}
```

Enum enables you to store all this values in same variable or vector and when you need to figure out which variant it is you use `match` statement like so:

```rust
let op = match &expr {
    Expr::Binary { op, .. } | Expr::Unary { op, .. } => op,
    _ => unreachable!("Operator is expected."), 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was already familiar with `enums` for implementing syntax tress and wanted to explore what other kinds of ways I can express. `dyn Expression` turns out to be the worst because it's just not okay. I found that enums for Expression is limited, in the sense, suppose you wanted to add a new expression type, you would have to modify the expression enum or create a new enum wrapper. What if instead I modelled the Expression with an empty `Expression` trait and generics to hold them with trait bounds, such that `BinaryExpr<L : Expression, R : Expression> { left: L , right : R, op : OP }`

Comment: @purple_turtle "suppose you wanted to add a new expression type, you would have to modify the expression enum" What is wrong with this? This is like saying the problem with functions is that if you want to modify it, you'll have to modify it. Even `op: String` here is too lax; `Addition`, `Subtraction`, etc. are significantly more type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

In your example **ExpressionPrinter** is a sub trait of the super trait **Expression**. This means that any type that implements the sub trait must also implements the super trait. It's not clear from your example if **BinaryExpr** implements both traits or only the sub trait **ExpressionPrinter**, which is the first mistake.

The second mistake is that you attempt to invoke **print** from something that implements **Expression** trait which the compiler cannot know.

You may try this, which is not nice:

```
pub struct BinaryExpr {
 l : Box<dyn ExpressionPrinter>, r : Box<dyn ExpressionPrinter>
}

impl ExpressionPrinter for BinaryExpr {
    fn print(&self)  {
        let mut s = start!("BinaryExp");
        s.push_str(&self.operator.lexeme);
        // Now the compiler knows that the left and 
        //right have a print method because it's 
        // something that implements ExpressionPrinter
        s.push_str(&self.left.print());
        s.push_str(&self.right.print());
        dbg!(s);
    }
}
```